# Point a domain to my website

Tags: subdomain

I have a domain name which i need to to point to  a sub domain of my existing website. Both the domain name in question and website are held with the same host so i have CPanel for the website (which has its own domain name and is currently online. Note the host does not provide CPanel (or similar) for domain-names only (i.e. without hosting).

I have seen subdomains and addon domains but from the description in CPanel i cant figure which if either will do what i want ... or even Aliases.

How can i point the domain name to a sub-domain? if possible. I do not want the existing websites domain name to appear in the url when visiting the sub-domain pointed to by the new domain name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using cPanel...  https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Setup+Edit+Domain+Forwarding

If you just deal with a registrar instead of a provider, typically you point '@.domain.com' to 'http://sub.domain.com' - where @.domain.com represents the direct name, domain.com.